# Mysql outfile to current working directory?

Tags: mysql, sql, into-outfile

Is there a way I can make the OUTFILE statement in a .sql file point to the path of the current working directory of the .sql file itself, without manually specifying an absolute path name? As it is now, the default location is the data directory of the schema that I'm working with (ie. C:\progra~1\mysql\etc\etc).

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Seems like scripting would be your best bet on this.  Using Perl or PHP to generate the query with the outfile in cwd.

Answer (score -1):

Not directly, but you can get similar functionality by using `mysql` at the command line.

First, some background: the `LOAD DATA INFILE` statement has a `LOCAL` variant, `LOAD LOCAL DATA INFILE`, that allows you to *read* data from a file on your local file system; without `LOCAL` it reads from the specified location on the server.

Unfortunately, the `SELECT INTO OUTFILE` statement *always* writes to the specified location on the *server*'s filesystem (which can include server-configured mounts such as NFS or CIFS shares); there is no `LOCAL` equivalent.

However, you can approximate such functionality by using the `mysql` client in *batch* mode:

```
mysql -e 'SELECT * FROM db1.tbl1' -B > output.tsv
```

The `-B` option causes the statement to run in batch mode, so the query results are printed in a tab-delimited way, with no borders. Using `> somefile.txt` allows you to redirect that output to the specified file, so you have something equivalent to what you want, without the `FIELDS` or `LINES` options of `SELECT INTO OUTFILE`, but close enough!

Comment: OUTFILE path on mysql server can be exported and mounted as local file path (disk) using appropriate scheme like NFS/CIFS etc

Comment: This doesn't help OP's question, but I've updated my answer to include that point, thank you.